# Heading in circles trying to install dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, compiling, cmake

I'm trying to install [darktable](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable) from its source. When I tried, `cmake` gave me the following missing package errors:

```
-- Missing intltool-merge
-- Missing appstream-util, problems in darktable.appdata.xml might go unnoticed
-- Missing jsonschema, problems in noiseprofiles.json might go unnoticed
-- Missing xsltproc
-- Missing saxon-xslt
-- No xslt interpreter found
-- Missing xmllint
```

I was able to install `intltool-merge` easily with the following command: `sudo apt-get install intltool`

When I tried to install `appstream-util` I started having problems.

I couldn't find a way to install it with `apt-get`, so I downloaded the source (`appstream-glib`) from freedesktop.org after following a link on the [`appstream-glib` GitHub](https://github.com/hughsie/appstream-glib).

When I built the source, I got a message that `glib` was not found, so I downloaded the `glib` source from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0) and tried to build that.

I got an error that `zlib` was not found, so I installed it with `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` which worked fine.

I then got an error from `glib` install that `libmount` was not found and I have given up at this point. It feels like I must be doing something wrong because this is really taxing to have to manually install all the dependencies of everything I want to install.

---

**Edit:**

After running `sudo apt-get install gcc g++ cmake intltool xsltproc libgtk-3-dev libxml2-utils libxml2-dev liblensfun-dev librsvg2-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev liblcms2-dev libjson-glib-dev libexiv2-dev libpugixml-dev` as suggested by [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) I get the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dbus : Depends: upstart (>= 0.6.3-6)
 libdbus-1-3 : Breaks: dbus (< 1.9.16-1~)
               Breaks: dbus:i386 (< 1.9.16-1~)
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2)
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.2)
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 229-4ubuntu4)
 libxatracker2-lts-vivid : Depends: libxatracker2
 systemd-shim : Depends: cgmanager (>= 0.32) but it is not going to be installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 204-5ubuntu20.19) but 229-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware : Depends: libxatracker2
```

Comment: Did you try installing `glib` from the repository (`sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`) before resorting to building glib from source?

Comment: No I couldn't see any repository info to add in order to install it @steeldriver

Comment: It should be in the `main` repository AFAIK - no need to add anything

Answer (score 2):

Please check here: https://redmine.darktable.org/projects/darktable/wiki/Building_darktable_20#Ubuntu-1604

I suggest that you do:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc g++ cmake intltool xsltproc libgtk-3-dev libxml2-utils libxml2-dev liblensfun-dev librsvg2-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev liblcms2-dev libjson-glib-dev libexiv2-dev libpugixml-dev

sudo apt-get install libgphoto2-dev libsoup2.4-dev libopenexr-dev libwebp-dev libflickcurl-dev libopenjpeg-dev libsecret-1-dev libgraphicsmagick1-dev libcolord-dev libcolord-gtk-dev libcups2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libosmgpsmap-1.0-dev git

git clone https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable.git

cd darktable
mkdir build/
cd build/
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/darktable/ ..
make
sudo make install
```

It builds for me on my 16.10 system, albeit with some possibly harmless warnings.

Comment: I've just edited my question, I get some errors when installing the first command. @chili555

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running? `lsb_release -d`

Comment: I am running Elementary OS Freya which is based on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Elementary OS is off-topic here; sorry.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't know as it was an Ubuntu derivative. I will flag my question for close :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use `apt-cache search`** to locate the package from the repository.

So far I have found all the dependencies that I have needed for compiling any of the source code from applications I have attempted.

I was also able to find dependencies for each of the missing ones from your list.

Use `apt-cache search` then for the filter use a regex expression.

These are the commands I used to find the dependencies from your list:

```
$ apt-cache search intltool
$ apt-cache search appstream-util
$ apt-cache search jsonschema
$ apt-cache search jsonschema
$ apt-cache search saxon-xslt
$ apt-cache search xslt.*interpreterxslt.*interpreter
$ apt-cache search xmllint
```

The package will be to the left of the description.  The output is the package separated by a `-` then the description.